# Meteor run Android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, meteor

I successfully installed all the tools required for meteor android build. When i run `meteor run android` The following error occurs

```
Error while running for mobile platforms: spawn EACCES
```

And when i run by sudo command like

> sudo meteor run android

I get following error:

```
Error while running for mobile platforms: Error running /Users/black_monk/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.wql4jh++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh
Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: don't run from sudo? If you have installed Meteor w/o sudo in the first place, sudo should not be required to run projects.

Comment: @imslavko when i run without sudo, the first error appear, it is same with iOS as well as for android. i cannot figure out how to solve it. i am going crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it,

changed all the directories to permission 777

sudo find /Users/black_monk/meteor_examples/todos/.meteor/local/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

and all the files inside it to 777 as well

sudo find /Users/black_monk/meteor_examples/todos/.meteor/local/ -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on a ubuntu VM hosted on Windows 8.1, but when I tried directly on Linux Mint 17 got the same error.

It worked when I started working on the partition hosted by Linux as I working on another drive and so probably a permission issue with NTFS or whatever.

What OS are you using?

Comment: its OSX Yosemite 10.10.1

Answer (score 0):

You need to `cd` to your meteor project.

```
cd <your_meteor_project>
```

Then run

```
sudo meteor run android
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `.meteor` directory and fetch at back from version control.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when I was trying to run android mobile application in ubuntu 14.04.

I got this error because I have created project in ntfs drive.
I can access that drive in linux, but I was getting same error as yours because of permission issue.

Then when I tried by creating project on desktop, error was resolved.
So use Linux partition drive to create and run project.